# Como Criar intervalo de 15 minutos SQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho um campo `timestamp` e preciso criar um intervalo de 15 em 15 minutos.

Como no Sql devo fazer isso ?

```
Data  = YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS
```

O intuito é uma analise onde eu preciso da quantidade de produtos vendidos a cada 15 minutos no dia anterior.

Comment: Seria um group by a cada 15 minutos? Se for isso tente GROUP BY FLOOR(`data` / 100) % 10000 *15

Comment: Seria um group by a cada 15 minutos e por dia. Vou tentar essa solução.

Comment: O que você tentou fazer? é qual o banco de dados é sql server ou mysql?

Comment: seria algo do tipo

data/hora         unidades

29/9/16 00:15         17
29/9/16 00:30         45
29/9/16 00:45         67
...

29/9/16 15:15         117  ?

Comment: Acho que estão faltando tags contraditórias.

Comment: Olá Mota, na realidade é no Neteza mas aqui não tem a tag, por isso que coloquei os dois BDs. É um relatorio OLAP  onde eu preciso  medir a cada 15 minutos  por dia.  20:00  - 20:15  - 20:30 e etc.  obrigado.

Comment: Talvez uma FUNCTION "arredondando" para estes 15 minutos.   https://4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-fgl-manual-html/index.html#fgl-topics/c_fgl_Functions_001.html